# 2D Matrix - Critical Warning (127005): Memory depth

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, quartus

I want to create a 2 dimensional array of constant values as synthesizable Verilog code.

This is for a module that provides the values of a sine wave to a DAC.

```
reg [7:0] sine [0:19];

initial begin
    sine[0] = 8'd0;
    sine[1] = 8'd6;
    sine[2] = 8'd24;
    sine[3] = 8'd53;
    sine[4] = 8'd88;
    sine[5] = 8'd127;
    sine[6] = 8'd167;
    sine[7] = 8'd202;
    sine[8] = 8'd231;
    sine[9] = 8'd249;
    sine[10] = 8'd255;
    sine[11] = 8'd249;
    sine[12] = 8'd231;
    sine[13] = 8'd202;
    sine[14] = 8'd167;
    sine[15] = 8'd127;
    sine[16] = 8'd88;
    sine[17] = 8'd53;
    sine[18] = 8'd24;
    sine[19] = 8'd6;
end
```

When I compile the code there are no errors, but this critical warning occurs:

```
Critical Warning (127005): Memory depth (32) in the design file differs from memory depth (20) in the Memory Initialization File "__.hdl.mif" -- setting initial value for remaining addresses to 0
```

Memory Initialization File:

```
-- begin_signature
-- DAC_SINE
-- end_signature
WIDTH=8;
DEPTH=20;

ADDRESS_RADIX=UNS;
DATA_RADIX=BIN;

CONTENT BEGIN
    19 :    00000110;
    18 :    00011000;
    17 :    00110101;
    16 :    01011000;
    15 :    01111111;
    14 :    10100111;
    13 :    11001010;
    12 :    11100111;
    11 :    11111001;
    10 :    11111111;
    9 :     11111001;
    8 :     11100111;
    7 :     11001010;
    6 :     10100111;
    5 :     01111111;
    4 :     01011000;
    3 :     00110101;
    2 :     00011000;
    1 :     00000110;
    0 :     00000000;
END;
```

How can I avoid this critical warning? Do I have to use the minimum memory depth?

Comment: Did you check if a ROM is inferred? Because chances are that a ROM instance is used and that these instances are organized in chunks of 256bit. I guess you could explicitly fill all unused mem with zero to avoid this warning or is there a reason why you want to avoid this implicite behavior?

Comment: @ChristianB. How can I check if the ROM is inferred?
I just want to reduce the overall warnings to a minimum.

Comment: In my IDE there is a tool called netlist analyizer which shows everything as block diagram etc.

Comment: In Quartus this is called RTL Viewer. It showed me a SYNC_RAM Block with type auto. Perhaps they are automatically generated if you don't use the internal memory IP blocks from Intel. But in the Internal Memory User's Guide has various internal memory types. Some of them have a minimum memory depth of 256 bits which would fit your first comment. 
I changed my approach and put everything in a 2D bit parameter within a System Verilog module

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.

Comment: @Zoe I posted my answer and accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the Verilog module with a System Verilog which now stores the values as 2D array bit parameter (The values don't change). With this modification the critical warning doesn't appear while compilation.

```
parameter bit [7:0] sine [0:19] = '{8'd0, 8'd6, 8'd24, 8'd53, 8'd88, 8'd127, 8'd167, 8'd202, 8'd231, 8'd249, 8'd255, 8'd249, 8'd231, 8'd202, 8'd167, 8'd128, 8'd88, 8'd53, 8'd24, 8'd6};
```

Answer (score 0):

The inferred memory device will usually be based on some quanta of minimum memory size which is dependent on the chip architecture being used.  Assuming that the inferred memory really did get inferred to a depth of 32, which is evidenced by the warning itself, I would argue that the best course of action is to modify the MIF as below.  Thus the memory will be fully initialized, and the warning check satisfied.

```
-- begin_signature
-- DAC_SINE
-- end_signature
WIDTH=8;
DEPTH=32;

ADDRESS_RADIX=UNS;
DATA_RADIX=BIN;

CONTENT BEGIN
    31 :    00000000;
    30 :    00000000;
    29 :    00000000;
    28 :    00000000;
    27 :    00000000;
    26 :    00000000;
    25 :    00000000;
    24 :    00000000;
    23 :    00000000;
    22 :    00000000;
    21 :    00000000;
    20 :    00000000;
    19 :    00000110;
    18 :    00011000;
    17 :    00110101;
    16 :    01011000;
    15 :    01111111;
    14 :    10100111;
    13 :    11001010;
    12 :    11100111;
    11 :    11111001;
    10 :    11111111;
    9 :     11111001;
    8 :     11100111;
    7 :     11001010;
    6 :     10100111;
    5 :     01111111;
    4 :     01011000;
    3 :     00110101;
    2 :     00011000;
    1 :     00000110;
    0 :     00000000;
END;
```

Comment: I modified the .mif file as you suggested, but after compilation the file is rewritten to the content in my question. Maybe the only solution for this is to use a 32 byte register and initialize every not used byte as 0x00 as @Christian B. had suggested.